# Problems persisting Core Data structures on iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, core-data, persist

I have an iPhone/iPad app using Core Data to keep my application data. Sometimes, even though I don't get any error messages, the data is not really saved so when the app starts anew, it's all gone. This problem seems to disappear after physically rebooting the device, but otherwise it's pretty random and hard to track. Has anyone seen a similar issue?

Also, it seems to happen more often in the iPhone 1st generation, less so in the 3G/3GS, and seldom in the iPad. Very strange...

Comment: I have a customer who is currently seeing this on a iPhone 3G running IOS 4.0.2.

I have not been able to recreate this but I do not have access to an iPhone 3G anymore.

I have a theory it might be to do with the time it takes the older phone to persist the objects as they include images.

Did you ever get any resolution on this?

Comment: I'm also encountering the same problem, any solutions?

Comment: Two years later, we still haven't found a way to consistently replicate this, but we have concluded that it's probably due to slow CPU and small memory devices. Look for low memory warnings shortly before or after your Core Data loss issues.